# Why does two's complement still work when working with large numbers?

Tags: math, binary, binary-data, subtraction, twos-complement

I was reading on two's complement recently and noticed that, when working with unsigned integers very close to the limit (mostly numbers large enough that the MSB is 1), subtraction seems to still work, even when the signed bit should still be filled with actual number information. For example, take 254 and 252, represented as `0b11111110` and `0b11111100` in 8-bits respectively. Subtraction would take the 2's complement of 252, so it's `0b11111110 + 0b00000100` which gives the correct result `0b00000010 = 2`. Why exactly does this work as intended?

PS.: I did also notice that if I were to take the unsigned numbers and look at them as if they were in the two's complement form, I'd get -2 and -4, which do subtract to 2. Is this perhaps a consequence of how the system was established and ended up being used by design?

Comment: How is `0b11111110 - 0b00000100 = 0b00000010`? Ohhh, you're saying -252 is the same as +(-252). I think you have a typo then. The thing that confused me should be + not - in your post.

Comment: (Ignoring the typo in the sign) Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: If he two's complement of an 8 bit number, `N` is (`256 - N`). And if 8 bit addition and subtraction is modulo 256, that is `N1 - N2 = (N1 - N2)%256`. If you replace subtraction of N2 with addition of its twos complement, you get `(N1 - N2) = (N1 + (256 - N2))%256`. Modulo operation is distributive, and `256%256 = 0`, so you find that for any values of N1 and N2, adding the two's complement of N2 is equivalent to subtracting N2.

Comment: @JohnFilleau indeed, that was a typo on my part. I'll correct it right away, sorry about that.

Comment: @ThomasJager I mean, in my understanding, since most resources I found analyze two's complement numbers as signed, the operation wouldn't work with unsigned numbers beyond the range signed numbers are normally in.

Comment: The above was a simplification. Two's complement is an operation on a set of bits, not on a value, but for mappings where the value of the bits is the sum of the powers of 2 of the indices of all set bits (N = b0 * 1 + b1 * 2 + b2 * 4 ... + b7 * 128) as in an unsigned 8 bit integer, then the simplification of two's complement to (256 - N) works out.

Comment: I've never done it before, but if you start designing your mapping (bit state to value) based on requirements of your system, and roll-over is a simple way to implement the addition circuitry, and you'd like to minimize the redundant values, and you want your mappings to be monotonically spaced, then the end result should be (I think) a mapping where the negative of a value turns out to be the two's complement of its bit representation.

Comment: @JohnFilleau thank you for the indepth explanation. I didn't think it'd be possible to represent the operation with modulus, but it makes sense since the values wrap in these systems. I think my main point of confusion understanding this is that I kept thinking the computer would need to convert unsigned ints into signed to be able to do these operations, but as you pointed out, the operation works just fine unsigned. Is it possible for you to add your explanation as the answer?

Comment: @Carmo not possible because it's saturday morning and I haven't drank my coffee yet. Please copy-paste to your own answer and accept if it's applicable.

Comment: @JohnFilleau haha it's fine, will do. thank you once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following John Filleau's comment:

> If the two's complement of an 8 bit number `N` is `(256 - N)`, and if 8 bit addition and subtraction is modulo 256, that is `N1 - N2 = (N1 - N2)%256`. If you replace subtraction of `N2` with addition of its two's complement, you get `(N1 - N2) = (N1 + (256 - N2))%256`. Modulo operation is distributive, and `256%256 = 0`, so you find that for any values of N1 and N2, adding the two's complement of `N2` is equivalent to subtracting `N2`.

My main mistake in analyzing this operation was (aside from overlooking the fact that the values wrap) assuming that the computer would need to convert unsigned ints into signed ints to perform subtraction operations, which, as shown above, is not necessarily the case. The idea of the complement works in both unsigned and signed numbers.